# Can creating an instance between Google Cloud Platform and Microsoft SQL Server allow me to transfer my GCP data to the SQL server?

Tags: sql-server, google-cloud-platform, import, instance, data-transfer

Hi we just recently started using Google Cloud Platform. We still use Microsoft SQL Server and SSRS for our reports. I have data that gets imported into GCP that I would like to use within Microsoft SQL server. Currently we use a python script to connect the two and transfer over the data but it is complicated. I was wondering if by creating an instance between the two I could directly connect my GCP data into SQL server? Please let me know if this is possible or if there are any other ways to make a direct data transfer between the two systems. Thanks!

Currently we have a script that connects to GCP imports the data and creates a CSV. The csv is then uploaded to sql server through SSIS and powershell methods. The problem is there is a limit on how big the csv files can be. Ideally, I would like to create a direct connection between GCP and microsft sql server if it is possible to transfer data to sql server.

Comment: Your question is very vague and lacks details. For example, what do you mean by `create a direct connection between GCP and microsft sql server`? Applications connect to SQL Server, Google Cloud Platform does not. My recommendation is to show what you have tried and your problem with details, code, error messages, etc. As written, I do not understand what you want or what the problem is.

Comment: Thank you for reaching out. So big picture is we have reports through SSRS. Those reports load in their data from Microsoft SQL Server. The problem is the data for this SSRS report no longer gets loaded into SQL Server. Instead it exists in GCP. I am wondering if it is possible to connect the two and just export data from GCP into SQL Server?